# Prolog recursion loops forever

Tags: recursion, prolog

```
inside(a,b).
inside(a,c).
inside(b,d).
r_inside(X,Y) :- inside(X,Y).
r_inside(X,Y) :- inside(X,Z), r_inside(Z,Y).
```

the codes above works fine, when I try to find anything inside a with: r_inside(a,X). I got X=b,c,d, that is right.
but if I change the last line of code to be:

```
r_inside(X,Y) :- r_inside(X,Z), inside(Z,Y).
```

then I type: r_inside(a,X), the program loops forever, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prolog has been invented from research on language processing, and it shows such heritage. The problem you describe is know as [left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion). Recently SWI-Prolog introduced tabling, following other Prologs model, as a general purpose tool to overcome this kind of limitation.

Comment: Thanks！I am new to Prolog, can you explain what's the problem with left recursion? I know that in other programming languages left recursion is not optmizable, but is allowed.

Answer (score 4):

So, just to be clear, we are talking about this program:

```
inside(a,b).
inside(a,c).
inside(b,d).

r_inside(X,Y) :- inside(X,Y).
r_inside(X,Y) :- r_inside(X,Z), inside(Z,Y).
```

And the query:

```
?- r_inside(a, X).
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
nontermination
```

To highlight the "nontermination" aspect of the query (without being distracted by any concrete solutions), we can use:

```
?- r_inside(a, X), false.
nontermination
```

To find the **reason** for the nontermination, we can use a powerful declarative debugging method based on **program slicing** (see [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)). The idea is to insert `false/0` at points in your program in order to find smaller (ideally: *smallest*) **fragments** of your code that *still* don't terminate.

For example, consider the following version of your code:

```
inside(a,b) :- false.
inside(a,c) :- false.
inside(b,d) :- false.

r_inside(X,Y) :- false, inside(X,Y).
r_inside(X,Y) :- r_inside(X,Z), false, inside(Z,Y).
```

With this version, we *still* get:

```
?- r_inside(a, X), false.
nontermination
```

I am now using <s>strikeout</s> text to strike out those parts of the preceding version that can be *ignored* because they cannot cause nontermination:

```
inside(a,b) :- false.
inside(a,c) :- false.
inside(b,d) :- false.

r_inside(X,Y) :- false, inside(X,Y).
r_inside(X,Y) :- r_inside(X,Z), false, inside(Z,Y).
```

So, we have reduced it to the following **explanation** of the nontermination, because this is the only remaining fragment:

```
r_inside(X,Y) :- r_inside(X,Z).
```

This *fragment* **by itself** already causes nontermination. No fact you add, and no goal you add *after* the single remaining goal can *prevent* this.

Therefore, to fix this, **you have to change this fragment**.

You can also explain the nontermination *operationally*, by taking into account the actual execution strategy of Prolog. In particular, you can argue using the *depth-first* aspect of its execution. However, **why bother** with such low-level explanations? You can *generate* failure-slices automatically, and they let you much more directly see the actual *reason* for the nontermination in isolation.

Comment: thanks for the debugging advice!
I find either <br/>
    r_inside(X,Y) :- inside(X,Z), r_inside(Z,Y).<br/>
or<br/>
    r_inside(X,Y) :- inside(Z,Y), r_inside(X,Z).<br/>
works out fine, I just have to write it in the "tail-recursive" form,  I am still trying to imaging the execution detail.

Comment: It is very hard to understand the exact control flow in Prolog, too hard for beginners. If you want to try it, start with the final fragment in my post, then proceed with the preceding version, then with the original code.